# Converting polyline to polygon in ArcGIS Desktop for floodplain map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, arcgis-10.5, flood

I'm using ArcGIS Desktop 10.5 and working with a flood map from FEMA, which uses polylines with distinct attributes for each hazard zone (1%, 0.2%, floodway, etc). I'm trying to convert these polylines to polygons.

I followed the guide Esri provides, but I don't seem to have access to Production Editing. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/production-mapping/creating-polygons-from-polylines.htm

Is there another way to create polygons from polylines, or an alternative to this to achieve the same results? My last resort will be manually filling each area with using InkScape.

Comment: If you want to try some different software, I can recommend the 'polygonize' tool in QGIS...

Answer (score 1):

As [commented by @mkennedy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245862/converting-polyline-to-polygon-in-arcgis-10-5-for-floodplain-map#comment385488_245862):

> There's also [Feature to Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-polygon.htm) tool, but you have to have an advanced license.

The [Feature to Polygon](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/feature-to-polygon.htm) tool:

> Creates a feature class containing polygons generated from areas
>   enclosed by input line or polygon features.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [ET GeoWizard](http://www.ian-ko.com/) Polyline to Polygon tool with either their ArcMap extension or standalone app to run these conversions (advanced license not required).